# Query Help (Foreach loop)

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
items(itemid, itemName, catid)

categories (catid, catname)

prices (itemid, open_price, close_price)
```

- Each item belongs to 1 category only
- each item has only 1 open_price, close_price row in the prices table

If I have 10 categories with 10 items in each (for example), how do I find the company with the biggest price change in each category.

I currently have  a php loop that runs and grab the top performing for each category, but was wondering if there's a way to do it more efficiently.

Thanks

Code:

`foreach category, run the following query:`

`SELECT c.itemid, c.itemname ,`

`100.0 * ( cp.close_price - cp.open_price )/ IFNULL(cp.open_price,1) AS overall_change`

`FROM prices cp`

`LEFT JOIN items c ON c.itemid = prices.itemid`

`WHERE c.catid=8 ORDER BY overall_change DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Do you want to do the working out in the php loop or before in the query?

Comment: if you've got a working PHP loop for the task but you want something more efficient, maybe you could show us the code you already have, as it'll help use understand better what you're trying to achieve and how far you've got so far.

Comment: @Spudley I was acutally wanting to do all the work in mysql

Comment: @user1062354: yes indeed, I got that, but if you show us the existing code, it would assist us in seeing how to convert it to SQL.

Comment: @Spudley please see edit above

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind draws (when two items are top of one category)

```
SELECT 
    cat.catid,
    cat.catname,
    c.itemid, 
    c.itemname ,
    100.0 * ( cp.close_price - cp.open_price )/ IFNULL(cp.open_price,1) AS overall_change    
FROM 
    categories AS cat
JOIN    
    items AS c
    ON cat.catid = c.catid
JOIN 
    prices AS cp
    ON c.itemid = cp.itemid
JOIN
    (SELECT
        c.catid, 
        MAX(100.0 * ( cp.close_price - cp.open_price )/ IFNULL(cp.open_price,1)) AS overall_change
    FROM   
        items AS c
    JOIN 
        prices AS cp
        ON c.itemid = cp.itemid
    GROUP BY
        c.catid
    ) AS max
    ON cat.catid = c.catid
    AND max.overall_change = (100.0 * ( cp.close_price - cp.open_price )/ IFNULL(cp.open_price,1))
ORDER BY
    cat.catid
```

... I haven't tested this :)